# How to add member to embedded class in run time by boost python?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm using boost python to bind c++ and python.

I want to make custom data type in run time.

For example this is excel file which include my new custom type infos.

Rectangle.xls

[image]

And i will read this excel file first and make new Rectangle type.
And i want to add this custom type to with c++ boost python in run time.

In c++ side, BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE macro will make functions.

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(HelloModule)
{
 python::class_<Temp> temp;
 temp.def(init<int>());
}
```

And i can bind like this.

```
PyImport_AppendInittab("HelloModule", &initHelloModule);
```

Boost python will bind this at run time but it can not edit at run time.
It can edit only when the coding time.
Is there have any boost python interface or way to make or import custom type in runtime?